# How do you multiply a number in a list thats ['40', '12', '55']?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to multiply the numbers in the list by 5 but it won't because it says "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

```
my_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
my_new_list = [i * 5 for i in my_list]

print(my_new_list)
```

Comment: But element of list `my_list` is string

Comment: I get `['11111', '22222', '33333', '44444', '55555']` (no errors). Note that you are using strings, not ints

Comment: Your list contains strings, not integers. Either rewrite it as `mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`  or convert them to integers : ` my_new_list = [int(i) * 5 for i in my_list]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list of string, so you need to convert them to int or float first:

```
my_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
my_new_list = [int(i) * 5 for i in my_list]

print(my_new_list)
```

or just define the list as a list of integers:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_new_list = [i * 5 for i in my_list]

print(my_new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on your error message, I suspect you are trying to multiply with `float` number, but the list is not in `float` format. You could format it to `float` before multiply like this:

```
my_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '.655']
my_new_list = [float(i) * 0.5555 for i in my_list]
print(my_new_list)
```

Output:

```
[0.5555, 1.111, 1.6665, 2.222, 0.3638525]
```

Comment: thanks for ur help! I tried doing that but it still wouldn't work prob cus of my code. Thanks tho!